# Ionic reusable component architecture

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, ionic-framework

I have a problem with a shop app architecture in ionic.

The shop app will have multiple screens with the same functionality, product listing, but with different data depending on the actual in app place, so there will be screens: category product listing, promotions, search, favorites.

They all will have the same list, with the same functionality, add/remove from favorites, minus/plus quantity, add to cart.

I'm just starting to know ionic/angular so in the first place, after setting up every controller and view for the screens i was using ng-include template i every view of them.

This worked, but i quickly realized that i will need to duplicate every scope function and variable, to every controller that uses the same list and just changing the api call to get diffident data, clearly that is not the right way.

So i made some directives, for every button in list item, quantity plus/minus, add/remove to favorites, add to cart.

This, again, worked, but there is another problem, every item has an minus, quantity counter, plus button in one row.

If i press minus or plus i want to update the quantity number, but it won't work, since setting product item in directive attribute and using $eval is getting only new copy, not a reference.

Was trying to change it also by the link scope, it changes, but the view never updates.

Every product is a model with plus and minus functions that updates a numValue property on it.

So my final idea is to make a completely reusable product list directive, with own view and controller, that way i would have access to everything in one place, first tests show it works, but then, how to avoid making copies of that directive just to change the api call?

Maybe i should just pass data from specific screen controller into the directive?

I just need some advice what to do, has someone made similar shop app with that kind of problems and resolved it? How you dealt with it, my app scenarios looks quite common for that type of app.

Comment: Too many questions here. Maybe try to split into separate more specific ones showing your code?

Comment: It is actually a simple question, i don't believe anyone who built any shop app with ionic hasn't faced such problems. If there is no answer then i think no one is making more advanced ionic apps.

Comment: People here tend to skip general questions or even close them. You may get better luck with likes of Quora.

Comment: Thx for the tip, but i also think that this question i not general, but very specific.
I've found the answer myself, duplicate the views or use one in include + generic multipurpose html with show/hide, you never know when you will need to change something when your client calls. As for the code, either copy it or use factory for shared functions.